# How to send a value from MVC to Javascript

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I have a catalog with several pictures, and I want to press one of those pictures and, without leaving the page I'm at, change the Full Image in one of my DIvs.

After searching the internet, I've found this:

```
<a href="imagem(@picture.FullSizeImageUrl" ... >
<img src="@picture.ImageUrl" ... />
</a>
```

that should connect with this javascript function:

```
function imagem(txt) {
    document.getElementById("imagemgrande").innerHTML = "<img src='" + txt + "' alt=''/>"
```

sending the image I want to my div with ID `imagemgrande`.

When I run the code and hover the image, the link that shows in the bottom of the browser gives me the correct path to the image I want to show (meaning the the java function should receive the correct path) but when I click, it doesn't do anything. I thought that the image tag could be wrongly created, and put a `alert(txt)` before the `document.getElementByID`. It doesn't even register.

Am I forgetting something, am I not declaring the javascript variable `txt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you calling js function in `href`? You should do it in `onclick`

```
 <a href="#" onclick="return imagem(@picture.FullSizeImageUrl)" ... >
```

and don't forget `return false;`

```
function imagem(txt) {
    document.getElementById("imagemgrande").innerHTML = "<img src='" + txt + "' alt=''/>" 
return false;
}
```

**EDIT**

You have to send a string as a parameter to `showImage` function. I've checked and it worked.

```
<a href="#" onclick="return showImage('/big_image.jpg')">
    <img src="/some_image.jpg"/>
</a>

<div id="imagemgrande"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showImage(imgUrl) {
    try {
        document.getElementById("imagemgrande").innerHTML = "<img src='" + imgUrl + "' alt=''/>" 
    } catch(error) {
        alert(error);
    }
    return false;
}

window.onerror = function(errorMessage, url, line) {
    var errorText = 'message: ' + errorMessage + '\nurl: ' + url + '\nline: ' + line;
    alert(errorText);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Tried your solution, but still the same.  It jumps to the top of the page (because of the anchor) but the image stays the same.  Even tried to put an `alert` in the function to see if it did anything, but no change.  Any other ideas?

Comment: you can use href just need to add javascript:   <a href="javascript:imagem('img/i1.jpg', 'imagemgrande')" > image 1 </a>

Answer (score 0):

use firefox and look at the error console -> menu Tools / Error console

1. did you check if image path is correct - relative to page?
2. test it - past the path in the browser along with page folder does it show?
3. double check - 
   is imagemgrande an image or a div ? if its image: change src

   ```
   function imagem(txt) {

       alert(document.getElementById("imagemgrande"))//what does this say

       document.getElementById("imagemgrande").src = txt + "?d=" + new Date();//force webserver request, optional
   ```

you can use href also like this

```
  <a href="javascript:imagem('img/i1.jpg', 'imagemgrande')" > image 1 </a>
```

See [image change](http://sel2in.com/pages/prog/html/js/imageChange.html)

Comment: the image url is correct, pasting it in the url shows the correct image I want.  `alert(document.getElementByID("imagemgrande"))` returns a blank box. Maybe that's the problem. The thing is, if I put the `imageurl` in the `href` (inside the `Imagem` function) nothing happens. The alert box only activates when I remove it from the href .